# Why won't JetBrains Upsource work with Firefox 23.0.1

Tags: upsource

I was trying to access a new JetBrains tool at https://upsource.jetbrains.com/

Even though I understood it should work with v22 or 23, accessing the url with my version of firefox (23.0.1) gives this:

*Loading Upsource...
Your browser must have cookies enabled in order for this application to display correctly.
You are using an outdated browser, Upsource may not be working correctly. Please upgrade.*

And yes, I have cookies enabled.

Is there anything I can do to get this to work with firefox?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Chrome 29.0 won't work either. Perhaps upsource is down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upsource was down. It's up again now, and works with Firefox version 24